# Tracking GA events while Universal Analytics process going on

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I am working on upgrading the Google Analytics to Universal Analytics, In the guidelines, it is mentioned that, it takes nearly 24-48 hours to complete the upgrading process. I need to know whether  it is possible to track GA event when transforming from Google Analytics to Universal Analytics process is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your events will continue to tracking using ga.js while the property is migrating.

The documentation under [Universal Analytics Upgrade Center - Upgrade Guide (Important Considerations)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/guide#consider-this) states:

> "...data sent via a legacy library or protocol to a property that
>   has been transferred to Universal Analytics will continue to be
>   processed and appear in your reports until it is deprecated in Phase 4
>   of the Universal Analytics Upgrade."

And from the Upgrade to Universal Analytics documentation within GA:

[image]

> To ensure you continue to collect high quality data, don’t make any changes to your tracking code until the transfer is complete.